# Multiple assign to previously defined variables in Perl

Tags: perl, multiple-assignment

How to assign return values to previously declared variables in Perl? Is there a way to do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($a, $b, $c) = first_assign();
 # let's say $a = "a", $b = "b", $c = "c"

($a, $b, $c) = second_assign();

# let's say we expect them to be "aa", "bb" and "cc" correspondingly
```

In this case all these variables will be equal to ''. So, is there some special way to assign to many previously declared at once?

Answer (score 0):

Just return a tuple from your assign methods:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c) = first_assign();
print "a = $a, b = $b, c = $c\n";

($a, $b, $c) = second_assign();
print "a = $a, b = $b, c = $c\n";

sub first_assign {
  return ('a', 'b', 'c');
}

sub second_assign {
  return ('aa', 'bb', 'cc');
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
a = a, b = b, c = c
a = aa, b = bb, c = cc
```

Comment: That was simple... Thank you very much!